# domain prints twice in image urls

Tags: laravel, vue.js

On a new installation of bagisto (laravel ecommerce app) when I use the CMS and upload a new logo to the channel, it adds it to the symlink, and everything shows up correctly in the public directory.

In my case it's route is:

```
https::/muskysmokers.com/storage/channel/1/zr6008b99hkwbr9HvINfYxt90wha3XY9fZtVRPQa.png
```

when I check the public directory the symlink works and the file is there. No problems there. If I go to that URL the image loads correctly.

Here's the problem:
When it renders in the browser, the browser (chrome and firefox) the browser some how adds the domain to the beginning of it. So it reads in the DOM like this:

```
https://muskysmokers.com/http::/muskysmokers.com/storage/channel/1/zr6008b99hkwbr9HvINfYxt90wha3XY9fZtVRPQa.png
```

Notice the domain is printed twice (once with SSL and once without). I can't for the life of me figure out what I've done wrong here. In firefox it prints the IP address instead of the domain.

How to see if for yourself?
Go to [muskysmokers.com](https://muskysmokers.com) > inspect element on logo (top left - image missing). You'll see the route listed correctly but hover over it or open link in a new tab and it has the wrong address.

I've changed my APP_URL and unlinked and re-linked the storage directory but still the same behavior. Can anyone help me understand what would cause the URL to print twice?

Is it something to do with my .conf file?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName muskysmokers.com
    ServerAlias www.muskysmokers.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/muskysmokers.com/bagisto-standard/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.muskysmokers.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =muskysmokers.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `http::/` looks _very_ wrong. I suggest you use an absolute path instead of a broken URL, ie `<img src="/storage/channel/1/zr6008b99hkwbr9HvINfYxt90wha3XY9fZtVRPQa.png">`, that way you'll also avoid an HTTP -> HTTPS redirect

Comment: Because I'm using a CMS I can't figure out where the HTTP::/ request is coming from. The database has the URL stored at "channel/1/zr6008b99hkwbr9HvINfYxt90wha3XY9fZtVRPQa.png" so it's not coming as an absolute path from the DB - its a relative path, as it should be.

Comment: What does your `.env` config look like? Specifically, the `APP_URL` setting. See https://forums.bagisto.com/topic/188/broken-image-logo-in-bagisto-with-causes-and-solutions

Answer (score 1):

After figuring out that my SFTP wasn't working, I tested it with the following values for my APP_URL and **this is what worked:**

`APP_URL=https://www.example.com`

`APP_URL=` <--notice there's nothing there, yes a blank field worked.

**What didn't work was:**

`APP_URL=http://localhost`

`APP_URL=http://localhost/mydirectory/public`

`APP_URL=http://www.example.com`

I'm on a LAMP stack and have my .conf file pointed all the way to my public directory so it makes sense that I don't need to point to my public folder here. It turns out that because I wasn't pointing to HTTPS when my server was redirecting everything to HTTPS it was breaking. Hope it helps someone else!